# The value of one of my ReportParameters is getting overriden

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following block of code.

```
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = LookUpFacade.GetReportFileNameFromDefinition(reportDisplayType.ReportDefinitionID);
                    reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
```

When I add a parameter called "Car" with a value of "Honda", it shows in the reportParameterCollection, but after I set the ReportPath, and I do a reportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters(), the parameter "Car" is there with a Values property (it can contain multiple values) that is empty (count of 0).

The reportParameterCollection has "Car" with a value of "Honda" but once I call SetParameters, the value is overridden in the ServerReport.GetParameters().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it had nothing to do with the code. I was passing in the incorrect parameters. I was passing a student id that didn't belong to the requested school.